# create URL from JSON file download image and display to left of text

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview

I am creating an android app, In the app data is read from a JSON file, using a list view the heading is displayed and when a user clicks the heading they are taken to a second screen with the rest of the data. I am having a problem with one aspect, in the JSON file is a part called image which shows the end of a URL (All stored in variables), how do I join this bit to the URL1 to create the full image url, download the image and display it to the left of the heading on the main screen, and since the first 2 JSON items do not have the image how would I load a default from the system (catch the error)?

It needs to start getting the images from the third item as the first two do not have the image field.

I have attached my code below and the structure of the JSON file.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ListView lv;

// URL to get Android Version Data JSON
private static String url = "http://codetest.cobi.co.za/androids.json";
private static String url1 = "http://codetest.cobi.co.za/";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> androidversions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    androidversions = new ArrayList<>();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    new GetVersions().execute();
}

private class GetVersions extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray versions = jsonObj.getJSONArray("versions");

                // looping through All Versions
                for (int i = 0; i < versions.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = versions.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String version = c.getString("version");
                    String released = c.getString("released");
                    String api = c.getString("api");
                    String image = c.getString("image");

                    // tmp hash map for single version
                    HashMap<String, String> Version = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    Version.put("name", name);
                    Version.put("version", version);
                    Version.put("released", released);
                    Version.put("api", api);
                    Version.put("image",image);


                    // adding Data to version list
                    androidversions.add(Version);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                HashMap<String, String> version = androidversions.get(position);
                String name = version.get("name");
                String ver = version.get("version");
                String released = version.get("released");
                String api = version.get("api");

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second_Level.class);
                intent.putExtra("name",name);
                intent.putExtra("version",ver);
                intent.putExtra("released",released);
                intent.putExtra("api",api);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, androidversions,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name"}, new int[]{name});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

   }
}
```

Layout file

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp" 
    android:id="@+id/image"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/version"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/released"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/api"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

JSON Structure

```
"versions": [
    {
        "name":"Alpha",
        "version":"1.0",
        "released":"September 23, 2008",
        "api":"1"
    },
    {
        "name":"Beta",
        "version":"1.1",
        "released":"February 9, 2009",
        "api":"2"
    },
    {
        "name":"Cupcake",
        "version":"1.5",
        "released":"April 27, 2009",
        "api":"3",
        "image":"images/cupcake.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a relative path, just append the string

```
String image = url1 + c.getString("image");
```

You should set the click listener and adapter within `onCreate`, not `onPostExecute`, by the way.

Comment: Hi, it fails to load as the first 2 JSON items do not have the image field so no data comes through.

Comment: Sure, so check that `c.getString()` actually returns something. Else, load some empty, default image. Your question was just how to load the partial URL, not handle the error catching